# Como validar si las key que se piden existan desde un Json con assertContains()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
from tests.mixins import ColectivaTestCase
from .operations import queries
import json


class AgendaTest(ColectivaTestCase):
    def test_client_query_agendas_resolves(self):
        response = self.graphql_client.execute(
            queries.AGENDAS,
            variables=None,
            context=self.build_graphql_context({'user': self.user_client.usuario, 'cliente': self.user_client})
        )
        self.assertMatchSnapshot(response)
        json_object = json.dumps(response, indent=4)
        print(json_object)
        self.assertContains()
```

Tengo unas key en un json pero deseo saber como validar que las que estoy pidiendo existan

Como utilizar el assertContains() para validar la existencia de las key dentro del json.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código en texto.